# Syntax for graphing 3-way curvilinear multiple regression interaction in SPSS?

Tags: graph, spss, non-linear-regression, multiple-regression

I'm attempting to complete my dissertation, but given I'm not a programmer, I'm running into trouble figuring out how to write SPSS syntax to graph my results. I have three continuous predictors and one continuous dependent variable; I need to graph both linear and curvilinear multiple regression interaction results (multiple hypotheses). SPSS ChartBuilder will let me graph two predictors, but not three. I figure there must be a way to alter the pasted syntax to add my third predictor...and I would greatly appreciate your help getting it right.

My advisor has requested that my line graphs contain the mean and +/-1 SD of one of my predictors ("extraversion"; and this would result in three separate graphs- one each for mean and +/-1 SD of a second predictor "learning goal orientation"; e.g., weak, moderate, and strong levels), while my third predictor is my X-axis of all the graphs, "Number of People". Any help would be appreciated, including if you could point me in the direction of a resource that would teach me the commands so I could try to write my own syntax (please do not recommend the Command Syntax Reference from SPSS; I already looked there). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the legacy menu option to draw multiple lines. You can compute the SD+/-1 in a separate variable and simply add that.